# Spring Boot, RestTemplate and request to self signed service - how to?

Tags: https, spring-boot, certificate, self-signed

What is the simplest method of configuring Spring Boot app with RestTemplate client, so it can properly communicate with self signed HTTPS API?

I created very simple TLS private certificate authority. I have CA-Root, CA-Intermediate, Server and Client. Manual here: https://jamielinux.com/docs/openssl-certificate-authority/

The goal is for Server to get certificate signed by CA-Intermediate, and for Client **to trust only CA-Root in order to accept all certificates issued by any of CA-Intermediates**. Certificates include proper extensions so chain certificate is not needed. Client should trust only CA Root certificate.

For a server, I set up Spring Boot web API with TLS configured, responding with JSON. I put private key and certificate signed by CA-Intermediate into keystore and used it to set up HTTPS endpoint.

As a client, I added CA-Root certificate as trusted into Firefox - it works like a charm. Firefox can access Spring Boot API without any problem. I can see my JSON answer on screen and browsers are not complaining about certificate.

So I thought it would work the same way in Java, and added CA-Root to default trust store (`cacerts` file).

```
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias my-ca-root -file ca-root.cert.pem -keystore "$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/cacerts"
```

But then RestTemplate request resulted with `SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target`. So I thought, maybe default trust store is not necessarily default. I created new trust store and specified path to it in app config via `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` and `javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword`. Still the same exception. Some suggested a key store should be configured with the same values as trust store. I set up both - no change, still not working.

Spring Boot is known for very minimal configuration required, and indeed when I request any external HTTPS API it works fine without any additional configuration. Example: https://api.stackexchange.com/

Based on that I assume no specific configuration is required, despite what other StackOverflow questions and answers are suggesting. They suggest to configure HTTP client on runtime, which should not be needed if you are using Spring Boot, right? Spring Boot represents higher level of abstraction and you should not need to touch HTTP client at all. There must be a way with minimal configuration, ideally, only in config file.

Any help, hint, anything, would be appreciated. Thanks.

PS: When I added CA-Intermediate to `cacerts` file, it works. But I don't wont to do it that way. Firefox or Chrome trusts only CA-Root and everything works fine. I want Java application to work the same way.